# How to call Toast to MainActivity from other file?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to call `Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Not enough balance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` from other file in `fun MainActivity.sell(){}`. How can I do that?
I get: `Unresolved reference: @MainActivity`.

Edit:

```
fun MainActivity.sell() {
     if (decreasingCurrency == "ZWL") {
                        var i = ZWLText.text.toString().replace(" ZWL".toRegex(), "").toDouble()
                        if (sellEditText.text.toString().toDouble() <= i) {
                            i - sellEditText.text.toString().toDouble()
                            ZWLText.text = i.toString() + " ZWL"
                            sell()
                        }
                        else {
                            android.widget.Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Not enough balance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of your "other" file.

Comment: See edit please.

Comment: It's just function `sell()` in that file.

Comment: Have you tried removing `@MainActivity` bit? In your scope, `this` already means the activity

Comment: Yes. After that @MainActivity appears again after I press "run"

Comment: fun MainActivity.sell(){
    //your code
    Toast.makeText(this,"Not enough balance",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

Comment: Or you can try to make this extension to AppCompatActivity instead of MainActivity if it is ok in your case. However removing @MainActivity should help